# Water pouring: Graph Implementation Problem - Shortest Path/Dijkstra's (?)

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory

**EDIT: Reposting; tried the problem a bit more and reposting. I'm genuinely lost at this point.**

Have this small graph problem to do for today, was wondering if anyone had any possible solutions/insight for it.

Given two containers, one of which can accommodate a liters of water and the other b liters of water, determine the number of steps required to obtain exactly target liters of water in one of the containers, or -1 if it cannot be done.

At the beginning both containers are empty. The following operations are counted as 'steps':

- Empty a contain er
- Fill a container
- Pour water from one container to the other, without spilling, until one of the containers is either full or empty

To get you started, we provide you a Node and a Graph class. Your job is to implement the function Graph createGraph(int capacity_a, int capacity_b), which builds a graph that contains all the possible container states given the capacity of two containers, and int findSolution(Graph g, int target), which does the graph traversal and returns the minimum steps.

You can modify the structures if you like, or build your own solution without using the provided structures. We will only test your int waterPouring(int a, int b, int target) function.

Hint: Which algorithm guarantees a minimun number of steps to reach a target?

My initial guess was Dijkstra's for the findSolution(), and attempted to translate some pseudo-code, but that didn't work out. I (think) I implemented createGraph correctly. Quite unsure as to where to go/if there's a better way to do this. Here's the code:

Thank you!

waterPouring.cpp:

```
 #include <unordered_map>
 #include <queue>
 #include <vector>

 using namespace std;

 #define EMPTY 0

 class Node {
     public:
         int a;
         int b;
         vector<Node *> neighbors;
         Node () : a(EMPTY), b(EMPTY), neighbors() {}
         Node (const int &a_, const int &b_) : a(a_), b(b_), neighbors() {}
             Node (const int &a_, const int &b_, const vector<Node *> &neighbors_) : a(a_), b(b_), neighbors(neighbors_) {}
    Node (const Node &tmpNode) : a(tmpNode.a), b(tmpNode.b), neighbors() {}
    bool operator==(const Node & b_node)
    {
        return a == b_node.a && b == b_node.b;
    }
    Node &operator=(const Node & b_node) {
        // WARNING: This operator does not copy the vector
        a = b_node.a;
        b = b_node.b;
        return *this;
    }
 };

  struct Graph {
     vector<Node *> nodes;
 };


 Graph createGraph(int capacity_a, int capacity_b) {
    // TODO
    Graph g;
    Node * capacityNode = new Node(capacity_a, capacity_b);
    for (int i = 0; i < g.nodes.size(); i++) {
        g.nodes.push_back(capacityNode);
    }
    return g;
}

 int findSolution(Graph g, int target) {
     // TODO: returns minimum number of steps to reach target liters of 
 water (or -1)
     for (int& node : g) {
      // not sure
     }
     return -1;
 }

 int waterPouring(int a, int b, int target) {
     // Call createGraph
     // Call findSolution
     Graph stateMachineGraph = createGraph(a, b);
     int steps = findSolution(stateMachineGraph, target);
     for (Node *graphNode : stateMachineGraph.nodes)
    {
            delete graphNode;
    }
return steps;
}
```

Comment: The vertices are the states of the pair of containers.  Edges are "empty A", "empty B", "fill A", "fill B", "Pour A into B", and "Pour B into A".  Breadth-first-search finds the shortest path to an acceptable state = shortest number of steps.

Answer (score 3):

If you are ok with a solution without using a graph (provided task description allows it), you can do the following:

Suppose you have two containers with capacities a and b and you need to get c liters in the end.

Suppose you have two containers with capacities `a` and `b` and you need to get `c` liters in the end.

First observe, that every operation you are allowed to perform moves `x * a + y * b` liters of water. E.g. if you are pouring water from the full second to the full first container you are pouring `1 * b - 1 * a`. You can continue to persuade yourself that this is true. This gives us the following equation:

```
x * a + y * b = c
```

This is a diophantine equation and it has a solution if `gcd(a, b)` divides `c` (see [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)). You can solve it using [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). If `c` is less than `max(a, b)` then either `x` or `y` less than zero. Suppose `x > 0`. Then you need to full `a`-container `x` times, pour water from it to `b`-container emptying it `y` times.

Example: `a = 9`, `b = 5`, `c = 6`. We have

```
-1 * 9 + 3 * 5 = 6
```

So, we need to

```
0 5 // Full the second (1)
5 0 // Pour to the first
5 5 // Full the second (2)
9 1 // Pour to the first
0 1 // Empty the first (-1)
1 0 // Pour to the first
1 5 // Full the second (3)
6 0 // Pour to the first
```

## But if you really want to use graph, then

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

struct Node { int a, b; };

class Graph {
public:
    std::vector<std::pair<Node, std::vector<int>>> nodes;

    static Graph Create(int a, int b) {
        auto index = [a,b](int i, int j) {
            return i * (b + 1) + j;
        };

        Graph g;
        for (int i = 0; i <= a; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= b; ++j) {
                std::vector<int> adj;
                if (i < a) adj.push_back(index(a, j));
                if (i > 0) adj.push_back(index(0, j));
                if (j < b) adj.push_back(index(i, b));
                if (j > 0) adj.push_back(index(i, 0));
                int da = std::min(a - i, j);
                int db = std::min(b - j, i);
                adj.push_back(index(i + da, j - da));
                adj.push_back(index(i - db, j + db));
                std::sort(adj.begin(), adj.end());
                adj.erase(std::unique(adj.begin(), adj.end()), adj.end());
                g.nodes.push_back({ { i,j }, adj });
            }
        }
        return g;
    }

    // Breadth-first search
    std::pair<int, std::vector<int>> Shortest(int target) const {
        std::vector<bool> visited(nodes.size(), 0);
        std::vector<int> dist(nodes.size(), std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
        std::vector<int> prev(nodes.size(), -1);
        std::queue<int> q;
        int cur_dist = 0;
        q.push(0); visited[0] = true; dist[0] = 0;
        while (q.size() > 0) {
            int index = q.front(); q.pop();
            for (auto i : nodes[index].second) {
                if (nodes[i].first.a == target || nodes[i].first.b == target) {
                    int j = index;
                    std::vector<int> path = { i, index };
                    while (prev[j] != -1) {
                        path.push_back(j = prev[j]);
                    }                    
                    return { dist[index] + 1, path };
                }
                if (!visited[i]) {
                    q.push(i); visited[i] = true; dist[i] = dist[index] + 1; prev[i] = index;
                }
            }
        }
        return { -1, {} };
    }
};

int main()
{
    const auto g = Graph::Create(9, 5);
    const auto p = g.Shortest(6);
    for (int i = (int)p.second.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        std::cout << g.nodes[p.second[i]].first.a << " " << g.nodes[p.second[i]].first.b << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << p.first << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is the same:

> 0 0
>   0 5
>   5 0
>   5 5
>   9 1
>   0 1
>   1 0
>   1 5
>   6 0
>
> 8